# Passing a string with hyphens gets evaluated as an integer (subtractions!) js

Tags: javascript, string, integer

I am trying to pass a value like "108-17-014" to a function through onClick...

```
hyphenatedId = "107-17-14"
dialogBody += " <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='class.exampleFunction("+ hyphenatedId +");'>link title</a>";
```

And inside class.exampleFunction,

```
exampleFunction : function ( hyphenatedId ) {
    console.log(hyphenatedId);
}
```

However, when I click the link, the console.log does not show "107-17-14" but instead shows 76 ... because it is interpreting the hyphens as subtraction operators.

How do I prevent this from happening?  Any other suggestions are welcome =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass as string

```
dialogBody += " <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='class.exampleFunction(\""+ hyphenatedId +"\");'>link title</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dynamically creating the text in the onClick at runtime, so what you end up getting looks like this:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='class.exampleFunction(107-17-14);'>link title</a>
```

You can see, then, why the values are getting subtracted first - there is nothing to indicate in the above JavaScript that it is actually a string.  All you need to do is wrap the arguments in quotes:

```
dialogBody += " <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='class.exampleFunction(\""+ hyphenatedId +"\");'>link title</a>";
```

Note you have to escape the quote, otherwise it will treat it as a termination point of your string construction.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous poster noted, if id="3-2-1" then:

```
'f('+id+')'
```

evaluates to the string:

```
'f(3-2-1)'
```

that then evaluates to:

```
f(0)
```

when what you wanted was:

```
'f("3-2-1")'
```

which should have started as:

```
'f("'+id+'")'
```

evaluating to:

```
f("3-2-1")
```

Comment: very insightful.  I appreciate the reduction, since it's much easier to see with less characters around =D